# Program expects a bracket, but there is one there already there

Tags: c++, arrays, brackets, mismatch

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#define ARRAYSIZE  15;


int main(void)
{
    //things needed
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    double xArray[ARRAYSIZE];


}
```

As you can see, my code should be in order but my program keeps telling me it expects a '[' where the xArray[ARRAYSIZE] is. By the way I'm using microsoft visual studio 2013.

Comment: \#define shouldnt have a ;

Comment: View the code after preprocessing.

Comment: Don't use macros, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 15
```

Take the `;` out of the `#define`.

With your `#define` written as is,

```
double xArray[ARRAYSIZE];
```

translates to

```
double xArray[15;];
```

The compiler expects a `]` before the first `;`.

---

Doing this:

```
const int ARRAYSIZE 15;
```

might be better...

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a const int instead of a define. Much better C++ practice.

Comment: Yea.  I mainly work with `Objective-C` and as such, I actually use `#define` on occasion, but no matter what the language, when I'm doing something simple like this, I use a `const int` (or `enum` in some cases, depending on situation).

Comment: nhgrif, `#defines` should be a last resort in C++ because of how they're applied (I agree that they are sometimes useful and/or useful). C/C++ are somewhat unique due to the phases of translation/compilation that occur. Say a `#define pi 3.14` for a constant may seem innocuous, but later in an unrelated place, someone else may declare a `double pi = 3.14159`. But, if the preprocessor version occurs first, the second, innocent instance will be translated to `double 3.14 = 3.14159`, which will obviously be an error.

Comment: Oh, I agree.  What I meant by my comment was that as I code most often in Objective-C, I use `#define` on occasion... but those occasions are almost always when writing Objective-C code.  I almost never `#define` in `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

after preprocess, your code is kind of

```
int main(void)
{
    //things needed
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    double xArray[15;];  // replace ARRAYSIZE with 15;
}
```

so you have to remove `;` in `#define`

```
#define ARRAYSIZE  15
```

Answer (score 0):

`#define ARRAYSIZE  15;`

Define will substitute ARRAYSIZE with whatever is there next to it.

So in this case it will substitute `ARRAYSIZE` with `15;`

So all you need to do is just remove the semi-colon in the define statement